# AMD graphic card not working after upgrading to Windows 8.1 on a Dell 3521

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, dell-inspiron

My Dell 3521 came with Windows 8. I recently upgraded it to Windows 8.1, but since then it is using Intel HD onBoard graphics. I installed the latest drivers for amd but still it picks onboard graphics card only. Also the [AMD Catalyst Control Center](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/catalyst-control-center,review-2012.html) crashes after every restart. Is there any way to make use of both?

Specs:

- AMD Radeon HD 8730M (Driver Version: 13.250.31.0)
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 (Driver Version: 10.18.10.3958 )

Currently I'm unable to use AMD, intel is getting selected by default and if i try to select AMD as the display adapter it reverts back to intel only.

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: first install the Intel HD driver and next the AMD driver. Only updating the AMD driver also never works for me. I need to reinstall both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What you need is graphics drivers from Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-15-3521/drivers). AFAIK AMD does not bundle Intel drivers with its graphics driver installer and Switchable Graphics functionality can also be missing completely with those or it just doesn't work when drivers are installed separately.

Get newest available graphics drivers directly from Dell, install and test if Switchable Graphics works after that.

Note: this is based on memories from about a year ago when I had to deal with this sort of situations on daily basis. Officially only solution was to use drivers provided by OEM, in few cases where CPU was actually AMD APU did AMD drivers work directly.

Comment: The user should be using the latest drivers from both Intel and AMD in order to solve their problem.

Comment: @Ramhound Problem is that neither of them, Intel and AMD, guarantees that their drivers work with Switchable Graphics setup, which original poster has. And in practice (coming from experience between 2012 and 2014) they often don't, especially with Intel-AMD setup. Because of this I'd recommend drivers from Dell even when they're most likely lightyears behind in release cycles.

Comment: I was under the false impression OEM drivers were required to support ther switchable feature but was recently corrected myself